# Haskell / Parsec - commenting out parseFromFile call leads to ambiguous types

Tags: haskell, types, parsec, hindley-milner

I'm working on some parsec code. At the bottom of the script, there's a parseFromFile call, where ParseFromFile comes from Text.Parsec.String

```
parseFromFile parserCode inFile
```

If I comment this out, my code no longer compiles and I get a host of ambiguous type errors:

```
DeleteMe.hs:47:18-23: No instance for (Stream s0 Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Char) …
      arising from a use of ‘noneOf’
    The type variable ‘s0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      parseSeq :: ParsecT s0 u Data.Functor.Identity.Identity [Char]...
```

with ambiguities like between the strict and lazy forms of streams:

```
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Monad m =>
           Stream Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString m Char
    -- Defined in ‘Text.Parsec.Prim’
  instance Monad m =>
           Stream Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString m Char
    -- Defined in ‘Text.Parsec.Prim’
  instance Monad m => Stream Text m Char
    -- Defined in ‘Text.Parsec.Prim’
```

parseFromFile must be disambiguating the type inference. What's the right way to resolve this ambiguity? Including the parseFromFile call will get it to compile, but I don't want to have to have to call it for that purpose. I could type annotate all combinator code, but that's messy.

Answer (score 1):

`parseFromFile` has type

```
parseFromFile :: Text.Parsec.String.Parser a -> String -> IO (Either Text.Parsec.Error.ParseError a)
```

So adding a type annotation to `parserCode` should solve the issue:

```
parserCode :: Text.Parsec.String.Parser a
```

This is not as general as it could be now (we might want to use `Text.Parsec.ByteString.parseFromFile` as well for example).
For that case, we can probably use something like

```
parserCode :: Stream s Identity Char => Parsec s () a
```

Comment: you have to replace `a` with the appropriate type of cause (or use _ when using PartialTypeSigs)